# Get all rows who have no associated data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, include

Campaign have attributes `:start_date,:end_date`

Invoice have attributes `:start_date,:end_date`

campaign.rb

```
has_many:invoices
```

invoice.rb

```
belongs_to:campaign'
```

I want to get all campaigns who have no invoices and whose `end_date` is less than current date.

I tried like this

```
Campaign.includes(:invoices).where("compaigns.end_date > ? ",Date.today, :invoices => { :campaign_id => nil } ).count
```

How I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're almost there. The example given doesn't work because it mixes the string and hash forms of `where`. Try splitting the conditions into two `where` calls:

```
Campaign.includes(:invoices).
  where("campaigns.end_date > ? ",Date.today).
  where(invoices: {campaign_id: nil}).count
```